# Give an Explanation for this SQL error "Conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type Which resulted in an out-of-range value"

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TRN_Hold_GetData] 
    @XMLSearch XML = '<DocumentElement><TRN_Hold_GetData_Custom><HoldId>0</HoldId><FromDate>17-3-2017</FromDate><ToDate>17-2-2017</ToDate></TRN_Hold_GetData_Custom></DocumentElement>'
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @HoldId INT = 0,
            @HoldNo VARCHAR(50) = '',
            @Party VARCHAR(100) = '',
            @StoneNo VARCHAR(50) = '',
            @FromDate VARCHAR(50) = '',
            @ToDate VARCHAR(50) = '',
            @HoldStatus VARCHAR(20) = '',
            @FilterQry NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
            @FinalQry NVARCHAR(MAX) = '' 

    SELECT  
        @HoldNo = doc.col.value('HoldNo[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)'), 
        @Party = doc.col.value('Party[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),
        @StoneNo = doc.col.value('StoneNo[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 
        @FromDate = doc.col.value('FromDate[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'), 
        @ToDate = doc.col.value('ToDate[1]', 'VARCHAR(11)'), 
        @HoldStatus = doc.col.value('HoldStatus[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    FROM     
        @XMLSearch.nodes('/DocumentElement/TRN_Hold_GetData_Custom') doc(col) 

    SELECT  
        convert(varchar(11), cast(OnHoldDate as datetime), 103), 
        ISNULL(TH.HoldId, '') AS HoldId, 
        ISNULL(TH.HoldNo, '') AS HoldNo, 
        ISNULL(TH.PartyId, '') AS PartyId, 
        ISNULL(MP.Party, '') AS Party, 
        ISNULL(TH.OnHoldDate, '') AS HoldDate, 
        ISNULL(TH.ExpReleaseDays, '') AS ExpReleaseDays, 
        ISNULL(TH.ExpReleaseDate, '') AS ExpReleaseDate, 
        ISNULL(TH.TotalPkt, '') AS TotalPkt, 
        ISNULL(TH.TotalCts, '') AS TotalCts, 
        HOLDSTONE, RELEASESTONE, 
        ISNULL(TH.TotalAmount, '') AS TotalAmount, 
        ISNULL(TH.HoldById, '') AS HoldById, 
        ISNULL(TH.Remark, '') AS Remark, 
        ISNULL(MEmp.firstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MEmp.middlename, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MEmp.lastname, '') AS HoldUser, 
        ISNULL(MEmp.firstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MEmp.middlename, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MEmp.lastname, '') AS UnHoldUser
    FROM    
        dbo.TRN_Hold TH WITH ( NOLOCK )
    INNER JOIN 
        ( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN HoldStatus = 0 THEN 1
                                             ELSE 0
                                        END) AS HOLDSTONE, SUM(CASE WHEN HoldStatus = 1 THEN 1
                                                                    ELSE 0
                                                               END) AS RELEASESTONE, HoldId
                             FROM   TRN_Hold_Detail
                             GROUP BY HoldId ) AS THD ON TH.HoldId = THD.HoldId
                INNER JOIN TRN_Hold_Detail AS HDD WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON HDD.HoldId = THD.HoldId
                INNER JOIN mst_Stone AS MS WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON HDD.StoneId = MS.Stone_id
                LEFT JOIN MST_Party MP ON TH.PartyId = MP.party_id
                LEFT JOIN MST_Employee MEmp ON TH.HoldById = MEmp.employee_id

                WHERE   HoldNo = ( 

                CASE WHEN @HoldNo = '' or @HoldNo is null THEN HoldNo ELSE @HoldNo END ) AND 

                convert(varchar(11),cast(OnHoldDate as datetime),101) 
                between  
                CASE WHEN @FromDate= '' 
                THEN OnHoldDate  
                ELSE convert(varchar(11),@FromDate,101) 
                END  
                AND  
                CASE WHEN @ToDate = '' 
                THEN OnHoldDate 
                ELSE convert(varchar(11),@ToDate,101)      
                END  


                 print @FromDate
                print @ToDate
          --???????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????? 
            --AND ( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(50),cast(@FromDate as datetime),103)= '' 
            --           THEN convert(varchar(50),cast(@FromDate as datetime),103)
            --           ELSE OnHoldDate
            --      END )  >= convert(varchar(50),cast(@FromDate as datetime),103)

            --AND ( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(50),cast(@ToDate as datetime),103) = ''
            --           THEN convert(varchar(50),cast(@ToDate as datetime),103)
            --           ELSE OnHoldDate 
            --      END )  <= convert(varchar(50),cast(@ToDate as datetime),103)  
          --????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????  


            --AND ( @StoneNo = '' OR ms.Stone_no = @stoneNo )

            --          --realse                   
            --AND  ((@HoldStatus = 'RELEASE' AND  ISNULL(THD.HOLDSTONE, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(THD.RELEASESTONE, 0) <> 0)
            --             --Hold
            --OR (  @HoldStatus = 'HOLD' AND ISNULL(THD.HOLDSTONE, 0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(THD.RELEASESTONE, 0) = 0) 
            --             --Partial
            --OR (@HoldStatus = 'PARTIAL'  AND ISNULL(THD.HOLDSTONE, 0) <> 0 AND ISNULL(THD.RELEASESTONE, 0) <> 0 )

            --OR @HoldStatus = 'ALL' 
      -- )

              --  print @FromDate
              -- print convert(nvarchar(20), @FromDate ,106)
              --print convert(nvarchar(20), @ToDate ,103) 

            --OnHoldDate between (case when @FromDate ='' then OnHoldDate else @FromDate end) 
            --and (case when @ToDate = '' then OnHoldDate else @ToDate end)
  END
```

This is my stored proedure; when I execute it, I get the following error

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Procedure TRN_Hold_GetData, Line 45
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Comment: What's the value of `OnHoldDate`?

Comment: @mayurgnu I think copy-paste-html-parse has failed you.  The XMLSearch variable being passed in, on face value, does not appear to be valid XML, so not likely to be testable.  Alternatively add a SQL fiddle and refer to that in the question.

Comment: ***WHY*** are you declaring variables like `@FromDate` which are **obviuosly** date-related as a string?? You should **always** use the **most appropriate** datatype - here, you should use `DATE` (if it's only a `DATE`), or `DATETIME2(3)` if it's a date and time

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime in the XML "17-3-2017" can be interpreted in two different ways - one of which 3rd day of 17th month, is not valid. Make sure you use explicit date formats in your XML in line with XML standards (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss)

Answer (score 0):

You really should have datetime strings in a universal format, as suggested by Phillip.  However, if you do not have control this should properly handle your convert pattern:

```
declare @dAsStr varchar(max)  = '17-3-2017'


select convert(datetime, @dAsStr, 105)
```